# analyzing strings in lua

Tags: string, text, lua

would somebody tell me, how to from text in variable like:

```
>Hello World
text,1000
text2,200
```

read:
1. line - if in line is > and line isn't logner than 50 chars then read, if not - go to next line
(part of this checking is:

```
if string.sub(tekst, 1, 1) == '>' then
    ...
end
```

but there is nothing about checking lenght of line.

next lines - impart text by "," and first get text from before "," then get text from after "," to the different vars (to analyse it by another part of script)

I'll be very grateful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your not entirely clear on what to do with the matched string (between > and the end of the line), as `read` is kind of generic, I just put it in a table.

```
s=[[
>Hello World
text,1000
>A line that is way too long to fit in this small space won't be accepted in the table.
text2,200
>Some text on the last line]]

t={}
for match in s:gmatch('>([^\n]+)') do
    if #match<50 then
        t[#t+1]=match
        print(match)
    end
end
```

This depends also on which  character(s) represent a [line ending](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_ending) in the string. possibilities are: `\n` (UNIX, Mac, and the rest of the sane world) or `\r\n` (Windows)

Comment: what's about parting lines by ',' ?

This text will be a config for NPC script
first line (if exsits >) is a NPC's hello message, next lines are items config:
item name, price

i just need a script that will analyse this code if it is correctly and update to database parts of code.

Comment: You should clarify your question to make people understand it. Aside of that, I don't know what an "NPC" is, and I could only guess what "database parts of code" means.

Comment: NPC - non player character in game. i want to impart text (by tile [>Hello World!], items [for example text 1], and item price [for example 1000] in variable and insert into database 

Sorry for bad english :<